# Python: Can an imported module use a locally defined module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have a script (`myScript.py`) that uses a combination of functions defined within itself, e.g. `printStatements()`, and imported functions from a `config.py` file in same directory, e.g. `myTask()`.

I want the imported `myTask()` function to reference the locally-defined `printStatements()` function, but I get a `NameError: printStatements() is not defined` message when running. How do I structure this?

Printing behaviour varies from script to script, so this needs to be bespoke & relative to the file it is defined in. I cannot import `printStatements()` into the `config.py` file, as I have multiple scripts using the `config.py` file, each with their own `printStatements()` function.

Edit - some example code:
`config.py`

```
def myTask(m, x, c):
    y = (m*x) + c
    printStatements("y: {}".format(y))
```

`myScript.py`

```
import config as cnfg
def printStatements(mymsg):  
    print(mymsg)

cnfg.myTask(3, 2, 4)
```

Error: `NameError: name printStatements is not defined.`

Comment: please add your sample code

Comment: One option would be using arguments like `myTask(printFn=printStatements)`. As the question currently stands though you really need to give more info.

Comment: Please ensure that the module and function names are accurate and there are no circular imports or naming conflicts between the two scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and clearest, option is to pass the print function along with the arguments to `myTask`, as also suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455090/python-can-an-imported-module-use-a-locally-defined-module#comment134810103_76455090):

```
def myTask(printer, m, x, c):
    y = (m*x) + c
    printer("y: {}".format(y))
```

and then

```
from config import myTask

def printStatements(mymsg):
    print(mymsg)

myTask(printStatements, 3, 2, 4)
```

in `myScript.py`.

In case you feel that is extra "work", writing the function as the first argument each time: it makes it a lot clearer what is being done. There are possibly other ways, but these do too much behind the scenes, in my opinion: Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be calling `myTask()` multiple times, you may not be inclined towards passing it as an argument. Another approach would be to use classes.

```py
class Wrapper():
  def __init__(self, printStatements):
    self.printStatements = printStatements
  
  def myTask(m, x, c):
    y = (m*x) + c
    self.printStatements("y: {}".format(y))
```